# Docker run with arguments from a configuration file

Tags: linux, bash, docker, shell, containers

I've built a docker image in order to publish a jupyter notebook to my team.

The jupyter notebook runs inside a docker container by running a `docker run` command containing numerous arguments (such as mounts and environment variables for AWS credentials).

The current instructions I published for running the docker require you to copy and paste the entire `docker run` command and execute it in a terminal window.

The script works fine, but I wonder if there is a way to specify the source from a file and run the `docker run` command with that file as the run configuration (including the run arguments).

The idea is to do something similar to what applies when building an image with a `Dockerfile`. Basically, you execute `docker build -f ./Dockerfile` to build the image.

Is it possible to do something like this with `docker run`?

I want to include my docker_run_configuration file (yml, json, etc.) at the project location and instruct the team to simply `docker run -f ./docker_run_configuration.yml`.

Comment: Sure why not? you can create a shell script (or powershell script).

Comment: That sounds like you're describing [Docker Compose](https://docs.docker.com/compose/).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The solution to your problem is **docker compose**.

Here are [the official samples and guide](https://docs.docker.com/compose/samples-for-compose/).

**Advanced TIP**

You can pass external variables to YAML like in the following example:

```yaml
version: 3

services:
  main_service:
    image: service-image
  environment:
    - SERVICE_OPTION: ${EXTERNAL_SERVICE_OPTION}
```

```bash
EXTERNAL_SERVICE_OPTION="A service option..." docker-compose up
```

Comment: some details in the answer's body explaining why compose is *the* solution would be nice please :)

Comment: In the above samples you can find all about parameters that are automatically translated in fully customized docker run command line.

Answer (score 0):

You can use an `ENV MYVAR MYVALUE` in your Dockerfile.

or you could set up `docker-compose.yaml` file,

and run this command for example `docker compose --env-file .env up`

- .env

```
MY_TAG=1.5.6
```

- docker-compose.yaml

```
version: 3
services:
  my_service:
    image: myImage:${MY_TAG}
```

Comment: env variables wouldn't work in this particular case :) arguments to `docker-run` are usually mounts, networking, ports. none of these can be controlled by the Dockerfile (which is only a blueprint for the _image_, not the container's config). but props for the mention of docker compose. more details on compose and links to further reading would be

Comment: also note that the name `.env` is autodetected as the env file and doesn't need to be passed via the `--env-file` flag. the flag is for names other than .env